# How can I allow the user to move / download a file from html FileAPI sandbox to his preferred location?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fileapi

I've been using html File API to create files from data received over the internet. So far its been fine.

Once the file is created in the temporary file system of a users browser, the user should be able to download the file. I am not able to achieve this. The files are quite large, larger than the size memory (RAM). So I can't just add a link and create an object url.